# Patterns in solutions to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have plotted solutions $(a,b,c)$ to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = n$ for $12000 \leq n < 12100$, rescaled to $S^2$ and projected onto the first two coordinates. (these are read from the lower left, across and upwards.  Sorry.)

[image]

While, over all $ a \leq  n \leq b$ there is clear tendency towards equidistribution, for a fixed $n$, there are marked patterns (or even no solution at all).  I've been struggling to find language for the types of patterns that are observing.  There are solution-free regions, there are linear patterns, circular patterns and other sub-varieties.

I suspect for fixed $n$, the solutions are clustering along the intersection of two vareties, $S^2 \cap V $ and I am trying to characterize the equations of $V$.

This is my theory of why equidistribution might be so hard to prove; it's because there are in fact patterns.

Comment: You might see Jim Cogdell's discussion of the three-squares problem... easily google-able.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no clustering of the solutions of $a^2+b^2+c^2=n$, even for individual $n$'s, assuming the number of solutions is large (e.g. when $n\equiv 1,2,3,5,6\pmod{8}$ and $n$ is large). This was proved by William Duke (Invent. Math. 92 (1988), 73-90), his paper is available (for free) [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002105063).

For more recent results, e.g. what happens beyond equidistribution, see the work of Bourgain-Sarnak-Rudnick [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0134) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05880).

Comment: I agree with you that any patterns, if they exist,  eventually go away.

Comment: @johnmangual: Yes. I should add that Duke's theorem is rather deep, it is one of the celebrated results of analytic number theory.

Comment: You might add Duke and Schulze-Pillot (1990) for other positive ternary forms, I put a copy at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Duke_Schulze_Pillot_1990.pdf  There is a simplified version in the corollary to Theorem 3

Comment: Note that equidistribution does not rule out "lower-order" patterns, e.g. enhancement near subvarieties, as long as these enhancements don't rise to the level of putting positive mass on these lower-dimensional subsets.

Comment: @LiorSilberman: I agree. I would be interested in any results in that ddirection.

Answer (score 13):

There is a $48$-element symmetry group of the space of solutions. This by itself will create the appearance of the patterns when the number of solutions divided by $48$ is small. Imagine choosing $k$ random points in the fundamental domain $a \geq b \geq c \geq 0$ and reflecting them around the sphere. Patterns will appear, simply because it is unlikely for the $k$ points to be uniform in the triangle, and any nonuniformities will be magnified by some or all of the symmetries.

In your case $k \approx 2 \pi (12000)^{1/2} / 48 \approx 14$ is pretty small, and this might partially or entirely explain all the effect you see.

Comment: These are not unlike [Wallpaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) groups?

Comment: This 48-element group is the symmetry group of the [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry)?  The cube [group](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Full_octahedral_group) would be $\big(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \big)^3 \rtimes S_3$.

Comment: @johnmangual Yes, the symmetry group of the cube. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_spherical_symmetry_groups

Answer (score 1):

Here I plotted some solutions around $n= 120,000 \pm 50$ and hoping a parallel algorithm could accelerate the process for $n \approx 1.2 \times 10^6$.  Here we notice again, distinctive, but fainter patterns.

[image]

At around $n \asymp 10^6$ these solution sets look pretty homogeneous. I'm a little bit nervious about floating point artifacts or other programming issues.    The solution sets look like [random](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2409) [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).  This might even have a name in the physics literature.

[image]

There might be approximate algorithms for $n \asymp 10^8$ .